# Group back unwinded array after match stage and keep the parent data/structure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Having some issues getting my aggregation to work. I have a `$lookup` where i join two collections, in the joined one I there is nested arrays with objects that I want to match in. The matching part seems to work by I'm not getting the structure back that I'm expecting in the `$group` stage after `$unwind`.

Here is a mongo playground with sample data https://mongoplayground.net/p/rWuX7ziT395

The original joined document has a structure like this where I among others match on some of the approvalStatus fields and I get the correct ones. But i also want to keep the fields in the "parent" i.e version, allHaveSigned, isLatestVersion etc.

```
"agreements": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "612c8d394459ebd2483a0920"
      },
      "agreementVersion": [
        {
          "version": 1,
          "allHaveSigned": false,
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "612c8d394459ebd2483a0921"
          },
          "approvalStatus": [
            {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "612c8d394459ebd2483a0922"
              },
              "publisherSignsFor": {
                "$oid": "60801bef03a9cd5f4a097e76"
              },
              "signingPerson": {
                "$oid": "60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8"
              },
              "isSignedByPublisher": true
            },
            {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "612c8d394459ebd2483a0923"
              },
              "publisherSignsFor": null,
              "signingPerson": {
                "$oid": "60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8"
              },
              "isSignedByPublisher": false
            },
            {
              "_id": {
                "$oid": "612c8d394459ebd2483a0921"
              },
              "publisherSignsFor": {
                "$oid": "60801bef03a9cd5f4a097e76"
              },
              "signingPerson": {
                "$oid": "60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df9"
              },
              "isSignedByPublisher": true
            }
          ],
          "isLatestVersion": true,
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"
          }
        }
      ],
```

This is what my pipeline looks like

```
db.songs.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "agreements",
      "localField": "agreements.songComposition",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "agreements.songComposition"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$agreements.songComposition",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$agreements.songComposition.agreementVersion",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$agreements.songComposition.agreementVersion.approvalStatus",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "agreements.songComposition.agreementVersion.isLatestVersion": true
        },
        {
          "agreements.songComposition.agreementVersion.approvalStatus.signingPerson": ObjectId("60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8")
        }
      ],
      "$or": [
        {
          "agreements.songComposition.agreementVersion.approvalStatus.isApprovedByUser": false
        },
        {
          "agreements.songComposition.agreementVersion.approvalStatus.isApprovedByUser": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "songs": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title": {
              "$first": "$title"
            },
            "artistName": {
              "$first": "$artistName"
            },
            "agreements": {
              "$push": "$agreements.songComposition"
            },
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "countAgreements": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "songs": 1,
      "sumAgreements": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$countAgreements.count",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The result looks like this and I get two elements in the `agreements` array where it should only be one and I think it is because I cant join on the `approvalStatus` fields correctly or missing something else.

```
[
  {
    "songs": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60debdaae7593406b682e45d"),
        "agreements": [
          {
            "__v": 0,
            "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0920"),
            "addedAt": ISODate("2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"),
            "agreementVersion": {
              "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0921"),
              "allHaveSigned": false,
              "approvalStatus": {
                "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0922"),
                "isSignedByPublisher": true,
                "publisherSignsFor": ObjectId("60801bef03a9cd5f4a097e76"),
                "signingPerson": ObjectId("60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8")
              },
              "createdAt": ISODate("2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"),
              "isLatestVersion": true,
              "version": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "__v": 0,
            "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0920"),
            "addedAt": ISODate("2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"),
            "agreementVersion": {
              "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0921"),
              "allHaveSigned": false,
              "approvalStatus": {
                "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0923"),
                "isSignedByPublisher": false,
                "publisherSignsFor": null,
                "signingPerson": ObjectId("60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8")
              },
              "createdAt": ISODate("2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"),
              "isLatestVersion": true,
              "version": 1
            }
          }
        ],
        "artistName": "My test artisters",
        "count": 2,
        "title": "Branches"
      }
    ],
    "sumAgreements": 2
  }
]
```

The result I would like to have looks like this

```
[
  {
    "songs": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60debdaae7593406b682e45d"),
        "agreements": [
          {
            "__v": 0,
            "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0920"),
            "addedAt": ISODate("2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"),
            "agreementVersion": [
              {
              "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0921"),
              "allHaveSigned": false,
              "approvalStatus": [
                {
                "_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0922"),
                "isSignedByPublisher": true,
                "publisherSignsFor": ObjectId("60801bef03a9cd5f4a097e76"),
                "signingPerson": ObjectId("60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8")
              },
              {"_id": ObjectId("612c8d394459ebd2483a0923"),
                "isSignedByPublisher": false,
                "publisherSignsFor": null,
                "signingPerson": ObjectId("60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8")
              },
               ],
              "createdAt": ISODate("2021-08-30T07:48:09.979Z"),
              "isLatestVersion": true,
              "version": 1
            }
            ]
          },
          
        ],
        "artistName": "My test artisters",
        "count": 2,
        "title": "Branches"
      }
    ],
    "sumAgreements": 2
  }
]
```

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` with pipeline,

- `$lookup` with agreements and pass `songComposition` as `id`
- `$match` `id` condition
- `$unwind` deconstruct `agreementVersion` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `approvalStatus` array
- `$match` your conditions for `approvalStatus` properties
- `$group` by `_id` and `agreementVersion`'s `_id`, get required fields and construct the `approvalStatus` array
- `$group` by `_id` and construct the `agreementVersion` array
- `$group` by null and construct the `songs` array

```
db.songs.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "agreements",
      "let": { "id": "$agreements.songComposition" },
      "pipeline": [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$_id"] } } },
        {
          $unwind: {
            "path": "$agreementVersion",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            "path": "$agreementVersion.approvalStatus",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$and": [
              { "agreementVersion.isLatestVersion": true },
              { "agreementVersion.approvalStatus.signingPerson": ObjectId("60d06fc53a7fc65be3787df8") },
              {
                "$or": [
                  { "agreementVersion.approvalStatus.isApprovedByUser": false },
                  { "agreementVersion.approvalStatus.isApprovedByUser": { "$exists": false } }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              _id: "$_id",
              agv_id: "$agreementVersion._id"
            },
            addedAt: { $first: "$addedAt" },
            __v: { $first: "$__v" },
            version: { $first: "$agreementVersion.version" },
            allHaveSigned: { $first: "$agreementVersion.allHaveSigned" },
            isLatestVersion: { $first: "$agreementVersion.isLatestVersion" },
            createdAt: { $first: "$agreementVersion.createdAt" },
            approvalStatus: { $push: "$agreementVersion.approvalStatus" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            addedAt: { $first: "$addedAt" },
            __v: { $first: "$__v" },
            agreementVersion: {
              $push: {
                _id: "$_id.agv_id",
                version: "$version",
                allHaveSigned: "$allHaveSigned",
                isLatestVersion: "$isLatestVersion",
                createdAt: "$createdAt",
                approvalStatus: "$approvalStatus",
                count: "$count"
              }
            },
            count: { $sum: "$count" }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "agreements"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      songs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: { $sum: "$agreements.count" } }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y98Me14gL-G)

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect with the sample data I provided but i found an issue when used in on my real data. When there is no match in the `$match` stage in the pipeline the "parent" document (song) is still present in the result. 

I've added more data to the https://mongoplayground.net/p/X8AGX5-BT_T and in the result there is a document with slug: branches-11 with an empty agreements array as there is no matching agreements. How would I go about to *not* include documents (songs) with empty agreements arrays? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind the above comment solved it by adding a `{$match :{
  agreements : {$ne : [] } 
}`before the $group. Or is there a better way?

Comment: @GameAtrix you have to add $match before group, there is no other way.

Comment: What is the reason you group with the __V/version key? Do we get a more exact grouping by using them or is it some other reason?